# Annotations not generated in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm struglling with annotations in Eclipse since no annotation generates code.
I tried several solutions:

1. Checking the "Enable annotation processing" under Annotation Processing in Java Compiler in the project properties
2. Creating a new Maven project (Java 17 with 2 dependencies: Lombok and log4j only)
3. Followed the directions in this tutorial [Eclipse getting started with AP](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_apt_getting_started.htm)
4. several mvn clean intalls, eclipse clean project, closing and reopening the IDE ...

here is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.annot</groupId>
<artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>annotations</name>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>  
        <configuration>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <version>1.18.24</version> 
                </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

here is an example class containing two lombok annotation and the outline (showing that no method was generated)
[image]
The annotation Processing window in Java Compiler in the project properties
[image]

neither the constructor is recognized nor the @log4j annotation generates the appropriate logger
[image]

The factory path
[image]

I'm used to use annotations in java projects with eclipse but i never encountered this problem.
Any idea to solve this? thanks

Comment: It does not work this way. [You need to install the Lombok plugin](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse).

Comment: @howlger thanks it works well by intalling the lombok plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this steps :

- Download the Lombok JAR file from https://projectlombok.org/download.
- Open a command prompt (CMD) and navigate to the directory where the Lombok JAR file is located.
- Run the following command:

> java -jar <Your_jar_name.jar>

.

- If the installer does not automatically find Eclipse, you may need to manually specify the Eclipse installation path when prompted.
- After successfully installing Lombok, you can verify the installation by checking the "Help" > "About" section in Eclipse. The Lombok version details should be visible there if the installation was successful.

https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: that's not how one installs lombok

Comment: @banan3'14 yes there can be multiple ways to install it.